# App Crash with Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL - CODESIGNING)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

I have created a very simple app which runs fine in the iOS-Simulator.
If I run the app with XCode on my iPad it also runs fine for a while.
Without having the iPad connected to XCode my app is starting but if I get to a screen where is needs to load data into a UIWebview it crashes.
If the iPad is connected to XCode or I run the app in the iOS-Simulator this won't happen.
I have reviewed the log in the Crashreporter but I have no clue at the moment why the app crashed.
To load the content into the webview I am using the latest AFNetworking version via Cocoapods.
The app only crashed if you call a ViewController with a UIWebview. The Webview is trying to load the content but is grey in the background. After 10 seconds the app crashes.

```
{"app_name":"ReportCrash","bug_type":"109","name":"ReportCrash","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","version":"???"}
Incident Identifier: 88FF066A-7260-4074-843B-FCF97E91D93F
CrashReporter Key:   bc8c7619326097730710faab8368d2101470e553
Hardware Model:      iPad4,5
Process:             ReportCrash [1979]
Path:                /System/Library/CoreServices/ReportCrash
Identifier:          ReportCrash
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-08 06:37:44.111 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL - CODESIGNING)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d9a844 0x194d80000 + 108612
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194d4217c 0x194ccc000 + 483708
2   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000eb350 0x1000dc000 + 62288
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194c9fa9c 0x194c9c000 + 15004

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d81aa8 0x194d80000 + 6824
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194c85998 0x194c80000 + 22936

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d9ae74 0x194d80000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e19548 0x194e18000 + 5448

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000194e14e58 0x194e10000 + 20056
1   Symbolication                   0x00000001905024dc 0x1904dc000 + 156892
2   Symbolication                   0x00000001904fa534 0x1904dc000 + 124212
3   Symbolication                   0x00000001904fa0b8 0x1904dc000 + 123064
4   Symbolication                   0x0000000190500954 0x1904dc000 + 149844
5   Symbolication                   0x0000000190501058 0x1904dc000 + 151640
6   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000e3248 0x1000dc000 + 29256
7   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000e1564 0x1000dc000 + 21860
8   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000ea0d8 0x1000dc000 + 57560
9   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000ec2a0 0x1000dc000 + 66208
10  ReportCrash                     0x00000001000ec364 0x1000dc000 + 66404
11  libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d9642c 0x194d80000 + 91180
12  ReportCrash                     0x00000001000e9680 0x1000dc000 + 54912
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1be18 0x194e18000 + 15896
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1bd70 0x194e18000 + 15728
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e19550 0x194e18000 + 5456

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d81ca0 0x194d80000 + 7328
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d963ac 0x194d80000 + 91052
2   ReportCrash                     0x00000001000e9680 0x1000dc000 + 54912
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1be18 0x194e18000 + 15896
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1bd70 0x194e18000 + 15728
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e19550 0x194e18000 + 5456

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d9ae74 0x194d80000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e19548 0x194e18000 + 5448

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d9a844 0x194d80000 + 108612
1   CoreSymbolication               0x000000018caf83e0 0x18cae0000 + 99296
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1be18 0x194e18000 + 15896
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e1bd70 0x194e18000 + 15728
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194e19550 0x194e18000 + 5456

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000004   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x000000000000000a   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000001
    x8: 0x0000000197be6000   x9: 0x000000000000002c  x10: 0x0000000000000015  x11: 0x000000019840a09f
   x12: 0x000000000000001d  x13: 0x0000000000074000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x000000000000014e  x17: 0x00000001000fc0f8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016fd23c70
   x20: 0x000000016fd23c80  x21: 0x000000018b408fb1  x22: 0x000000016fd23cb0  x23: 0x00000001001090e0
   x24: 0x00000001000ff000  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd23e78  fp: 0x000000016fd23c60   lr: 0x0000000194cd953c
    sp: 0x000000016fd23c30   pc: 0x0000000194d9a844 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x1000dc000 - 0x1000fbfff ReportCrash arm64  <be0d5e27af94399094225fadcd185ac1> /System/Library/CoreServices/ReportCrash
0x120024000 - 0x12004bfff dyld arm64  <628da833271c3f9bb8d44c34060f55e0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x186a88000 - 0x186a8bfff Accelerate arm64  <fe3a369c06d23c4fb0c053964eab7e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x186a98000 - 0x186c6bfff vImage arm64  <35138843dfb73924908202512ca0e178> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x186c6c000 - 0x186d0bfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <d1836bd233333aadb94d6f848f22251e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x186d0c000 - 0x18706ffff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <8c24faa666963e4d905cd73fef3b7324> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x187070000 - 0x1870c7fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f9b2f7b3ea2938bf99adbdf9e4cc159c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1870c8000 - 0x1870e7fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <bd7cb5c078cf3d7bba947c31f3d802ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1870e8000 - 0x1870ebfff vecLib arm64  <c29a5c80dbf73db7b35ea6912c01192a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1877b4000 - 0x18791ffff CFNetwork arm64  <ff953c5b90ca320a8141e65032f41ed0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x187bc4000 - 0x187d4ffff CoreFoundation arm64  <300ef390e53f36d28f63ca9f105ad86e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x187d50000 - 0x187eaffff CoreGraphics arm64  <c16c7faf626234f1992f1e7f27ef992f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x188758000 - 0x188997fff Foundation arm64  <a698ba21ece734889c74bf2c20e6aea4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x188bc8000 - 0x188c37fff IOKit arm64  <5bc819eb63983f50a09166eed596c650> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x189928000 - 0x1899a3fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <21036a78054f3e3b8d018be04c3b6bf4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18aa54000 - 0x18aaabfff Security arm64  <fb91c2689923333cb17521e27f744a5a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18ac18000 - 0x18ac7ffff SystemConfiguration arm64  <58592ccb97af3ceb9008b388c1692d0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x18b978000 - 0x18b97ffff AggregateDictionary arm64  <484f1eccbfff3abc8f349ceee0d1e986> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18c2c0000 - 0x18c2effff BackBoardServices arm64  <603da8ec3d06386997bdd080b88ac791> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18c748000 - 0x18c74bfff ConstantClasses arm64  <fd7267eeb9ba32dd869dd68390c76706> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18cae0000 - 0x18cb53fff CoreSymbolication arm64  <455834aaef023ebb9fe927af93809ae6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/CoreSymbolication
0x18cc74000 - 0x18cc7bfff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <15b85b4c1d603dc99361e3f2ec526f11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18d860000 - 0x18d87bfff GraphicsServices arm64  <bb095b54f11b3281829a605b14c2bf47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1900ac000 - 0x1900c7fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <d1ed07fae1eb3fcd9a9af8dd842e84a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1904dc000 - 0x190537fff Symbolication arm64  <9c001ed6720134fb80c95092918181e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Symbolication
0x192728000 - 0x192733fff XPCObjects arm64  <2f6096e0d8e03d74a3342f515a5c8eb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x193c24000 - 0x193c3ffff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <ff151c2846b4368b9494a50188cfbe47> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x193c64000 - 0x193c7ffff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <1b86018e2cb13068ac042f284d022cdc> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x193ca4000 - 0x193ca7fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <658ec4d13ebe3bd6ba6384b6e72d2d2b> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x193ed8000 - 0x193eebfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <a2569621348b3769ae106827cb738cd9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x193efc000 - 0x193f53fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <5d5261c7a04230798de2288bc527d12a> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x193f54000 - 0x193f73fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <010b41d6195d33d49afe0ed60f33078c> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1940f4000 - 0x1942b3fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <644c8cb8dcd8361ea4ce800d128990ed> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1942c0000 - 0x1942c3fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <ffe2212571e6329aa2a064f4761d9a85> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1946a4000 - 0x19485ffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <16c4bf64e3133189be2061a0476fcf52> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1949a8000 - 0x194a67fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <d25694cbb3f2336fa7c758b24ae66b37> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x194a68000 - 0x194abbfff libstdc++.6.dylib arm64  <692601ba4797329b96ff0cd7db3faabd> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x194af4000 - 0x194bdffff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <94ada6329bdf3570b4318a3e10558771> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x194c0c000 - 0x194c1ffff libz.1.dylib arm64  <070746af9ba53c1ca2d1bf0d2067fb80> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x194c20000 - 0x194c27fff libcache.dylib arm64  <2ec87620868a3a7c9493ddd7c0fc9e40> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x194c28000 - 0x194c33fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <2a44b96b0c213b31b1ed00c2adf7c319> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x194c34000 - 0x194c37fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <8c572b4049833618aa3fd259e90bb363> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x194c38000 - 0x194c3ffff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <1a926234ac0e31b08e251dce2ab4d1ef> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x194c40000 - 0x194c7ffff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <2fc1a6330a70373a831f6b9ea7d07e21> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x194c80000 - 0x194c9bfff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <4fc10dee73b43e0a951b5c2451fbf6f1> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x194c9c000 - 0x194c9ffff libdyld.dylib arm64  <5b19195e956f3a20b2d637702fdaf37e> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x194ca0000 - 0x194ca7fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <86062ec580873150851ca3207405f88f> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x194ca8000 - 0x194caffff libmacho.dylib arm64  <5b0aaeec01483c9a89c9ff819accc0cf> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x194cb0000 - 0x194cb3fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <43e5fd04a6b43fc6a61f39be13d05d22> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x194cb4000 - 0x194cc7fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <7a6caf55803b36db8fa778a0668c78ee> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x194cc8000 - 0x194ccbfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <34da6d5e3c1b362f97260a883005b828> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x194ccc000 - 0x194d4bfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <e3a5b6542768396cb2fdf7ed88d34dae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x194d4c000 - 0x194d4ffff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <62583fa6ea443124b29132c80bfb36a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x194d50000 - 0x194d5bfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <66f1e6bf8df8395fbf81310f454151cb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x194d5c000 - 0x194d7ffff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <997a5c8b01d43cf6bc4ad7e534d3a7b0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x194d80000 - 0x194d9ffff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <8865e86b2993391e82944c5508ea16d3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x194da0000 - 0x194dbffff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <ca91cb158d353926b7a0248d661901ad> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x194dc0000 - 0x194ddbfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <3acd36537b1533b6a7ae98d6268c8ea7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x194ddc000 - 0x194e03fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <24c60c94b8d03d80b1c2aee556a52539> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x194e04000 - 0x194e0ffff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <2b70acad1c443f0da579465c4681cb96> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x194e10000 - 0x194e17fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <c9d9cda55cb83dbc9b2c6a78605ecc67> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x194e18000 - 0x194e1ffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <87037f808e6436d7a3669857d0ac5c4f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x194e20000 - 0x194e23fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <cbf7b62c54f83ed89ab2c4b4810cec58> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x194e24000 - 0x194e27fff libsystem_stats.dylib arm64  <e167c586dea435ffb14ed460363c1547> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
0x194e28000 - 0x194e2ffff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b1bdf22bcb83360fb68040abdb5578fb> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x194e30000 - 0x194e53fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <7077afbad955309d8cb9965960c781f3> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: Have you [enabled zombie objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5387006/269970) to help narrow down some possibilities?

Comment: are you a registered member of Apple's Developer Program?  With it, you can easily generate code signing certificates which you'll need to install a freshly built test app onto your device.

Comment: I am a registered member.

Answer (score 1):

It's occurring because Your application may be taking too long to launch. It is given unlimited time when launching from Xcode.

You can fix it by

```
- select Project from Project navigation Bar
  - Editor menu
    - Add Build Phase
      - Add Run Script Build Phase
        - Add as a "Run Script" =>  "codesign -fs "iPhone Developer" ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

From above script remove double quotation *("...")*.

Comment: I will give it a try. But my app is starting without any crash. It only crashes if it comes to load content into an UIWebview no matter on which ViewController.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. My problem isn't that the app is crashing on starting but on using any UIWebview which is inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar crash while manual code resigning. I was changing the provisioning profile which had below key in entitlements file -

```
 <key>get-task-allow</key>
 <true/>
```

On Removing this key from the entitlement file and resigning it, I was successfully able to run the App on device.